# Display Referring Category on single post?

Tags: categories, single

My site is built in such a way that every single post (in a custom post type) is accessed via a category archive (custom taxonomy). Every post may have more than one category assigned, but I want to display only the category from the archive that came previously.

Lets say post "Bob Brooks" is assigned cat apple, banana and carrot. I browse to site.com/category/carrot/ and click on the result "Bob Brooks". on site.com/bob-brooks/, I want it to show "carrot" in a subheader on the template, but not the other categories. And I obviously want it to show the correct cat dynamically.

How do I do that?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any other good way or not, but you can use `session`.

Comment: I actually figured out the answer on my own. The site generates a cookie on the initial search field to save a person's search term, and that term is the info I need. So I just set the cookie value as a php variable and stick it where I need it. Probably not the best method, but it's working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a simple way to do that, but one solution which can work is get an HTTP referrer and parse it to get the category name.

In PHP you can get a referrer like this - $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']